# Linux reverse sorting giving wrong results

Tags: linux, bash

I have a data which is of the following format:

```
 diplomat 9.35003521034e-07
 golden 0.0
 projection 5.75975635192e-06
 Harvey 9.25224016662e-08
 Omelianchuk 8.77038876791e-08
 stern 6.23335680688e-08
 insecurity 0.0
 century 0.000814828405418
 Karadzic 0.0
 Vernon 5.56509185654e-08
 music 0.0
 therefore 0.000486949687357
 Diabetes 0.0
 yahoo 0.0
 meteorologist 6.80717342684e-08
 Aynsley-Green 0.0
 intake 0.0
 morally 0.0
 locker 0.0
 Colombia 0.0
 Mahela 1.08371146396e-07
```

I want to sort the data according to the values in the second column. I used the linux command

```
 sort -r -g -t $'\t' -k2,2
```

I used -g for generic sorting. It is still not giving me the correct output. I am getting result out of order.

The output I got was:

```
yahoo 0.0
Vernon 5.56509185654e-08
therefore 0.000486949687357
stern 6.23335680688e-08 
projection 5.75975635192e-06
Omelianchuk 8.77038876791e-08
music 0.0
morally 0.0
meteorologist 6.80717342684e-08
Mahela 1.08371146396e-07
locker 0.0
Karadzic 0.0
intake 0.0
insecurity 0.0
Harvey 9.25224016662e-08
golden 0.0
diplomat 9.35003521034e-07
Diabetes 0.0
Colombia 0.0
century 0.000814828405418
Aynsley-Green 0.0
```

I even tried multiplying the values with 10 following by 7 zeros and then sorting, but still that also didn't work.

```
awk '{print $2*100000000}' infile
```

How can I fix this? Please help!

Comment: The sample data seem to have space separator and you are specifying tab separator in the sort command. Isn't this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to sort the data with

```
sort -r -g -t' ' -k3,3
```

and the output looks fine to me. Your separator is space. And as there is a space at the beginning of each line, the number is actually third column.

I got this output

```
 century 0.000814828405418
 therefore 0.000486949687357
 projection 5.75975635192e-06
 diplomat 9.35003521034e-07
 Mahela 1.08371146396e-07
 Harvey 9.25224016662e-08
 Omelianchuk 8.77038876791e-08
 meteorologist 6.80717342684e-08
 stern 6.23335680688e-08
 Vernon 5.56509185654e-08
 yahoo 0.0
 music 0.0
 morally 0.0
 locker 0.0
 Karadzic 0.0
 intake 0.0
 insecurity 0.0
 golden 0.0
 Diabetes 0.0
 Colombia 0.0
 Aynsley-Green 0.0
```

Comment: no still it's not working. I have a huge data which consists of this format. It kinda jumbles the order again. I have words with values zeros in between the words with values higher than 0s.

Comment: I'm unable to help as I'm unable to reproduce because I don't have your data which cause the problem (as you see for the provided data it worked just fine). Please double check if there are no other issues with the data (inconsistent column number etc.), it is unlikely that there is a problem with `sort` itself.

Comment: I have added the output I get also.

Comment: I used the command from my answer and got correct output (updated in the answer). What operating system and what version of `sort` command do you have?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 and I just used the sort command in the terminal

Comment: @Rudhra: Sounds like it shouldn't be a problem. Can you upload the file somewhere so that we exclude a copy-paste error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84400/discussion-between-rudhra-and-buff).

Comment: It works perfectly well now :) Thanks a lot for the help and guidance! and sorry for a very late reply